# Does TFS with VS2012/VS2013 track every local save?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Thinking about using `Team Foundation Server` with `VS2012` or `VS2013`.  Does `TFS` track every single local change?  For example.  If I save a file 10 times locally even though I don't check in, will every one of those local saves be checked in on the TFS server so anyone on the team can see?  Of does it just send to the server the latest saved version of the file when you check in?  I'm not looking for it to do this because it wouldn't seem to make sense unless a manager wanted to track your hours or something.

Comment: Git doesn't stage every file save operation, just the commits you do. I don't know TFVC though.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN describes the checkin process [over here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181407.aspx). It is stated there, that...

> ... all the included file changes from your workspace along with the comment, check-in notes, and links to related work items are stored on the server as a single changeset on your server.

That means that only the last version of your changes made locally will make it into the changeset, onto the server and to your coworkers. You can save as often as you want beforehand, the server won't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:
I can't think of any SCM that works that way.

Here's how it works, with pretty much any version control system (the terminology will differ from SCM to SCM, but the concepts are the same):

You start modifying a file.
You change the file as much as you want. When you're done, you commit it/check it in. 
The contents of the file at that point in time are what's stored in the SCM. No intervening changes are stored.

Comment: I've never seen other SCMs do this except for SharePoint which isn't a SCM but saw that it showed every single save I made on the server.  I'm trying to make the case for `Git` instead of `TFS` because I'm the only developer on this project.  I think TFS is too much overhead for one developer but I'm not sure.  I think someone suggested TFS because they want to track my work?

Comment: It could be that you misunderstood the meaning of "tracking your work" -- TFS has integrated project management tools. It's not about looking at everything you've done, it's about keeping an eye on the health and progress of the project as a whole. TFS also has continuous integration built in, which can make life easier even as a solo developer. Last, if you like Git, you can still use Git from TFS and get all of the other benefits.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding "tracking my work." Being the only developer, working remote, traveling quite a lot, I thought that TFS was going to be something that slowed down daily development. I just thought a more lightweight SCM like git would be more appropriate in this case. I've heard TFS has problems working offline but maybe they've fixed those issues.  Maybe the project management tools will be useful as you explained.  So I can work for a few days "locally" using TFS but the server will only see the latest version of what I check in even if that's every few days?

Comment: TFS has two version control options: Git and TFVC. Git is just a plain old Git repo, hosted in TFS, giving you access to everything else TFS has to offer.

Comment: Very helpful.  So with TFS a project manager won't be able to really track your hourly work any better than they could with `VSS` or `git`, `svn`, etc?

Comment: No. TFS is not a time tracking tool, and it's not intended to be.

Comment: You can always try https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ae71e276-e35e-47d3-915d-61a5a38de33b TFS Auto Shelve for Visual Studio 2013 not exactly what you want but a solution nonetheless